# np.busday_count from pandas timestamp columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to return a Pandas series containing the difference in number of business days between two dataframe columns containing dates: "Delivery Date" and "Pickup Date".

I can tell from df.dtypes that my two columns of dates are datetime64[ns]. From what I've seen, the easiest way to find the number of business days between them is numpy.busday_count.

```py
ID          Pickup Date Delivery Date
1004817295  2019-08-30  2019-09-02
1004833653  2019-08-30  NaT
1004852236  2019-08-30  2019-09-02
1012884202  2019-10-21  2019-10-22
1037931016  2019-08-19  2019-08-22


df.dropna(axis=0,subset=['Delivery Date']).apply(lambda x: np.busday_count(x['Pickup Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),x['Delivery Date'].values.astype('datetime64[D]'),axis=1))
```

I received the following error

KeyError: ('Pickup Date', 'occurred at index Pickup Date')

which makes me think I'm missing something with my axes somewhere. What am I missing? Is this even the most efficient approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the missing value might be giving the error

```
numbusdays = []
for a,b in zip(list(df['Pickup Date']),list(df['Delivery Date'])):
    if str(a) != 'NaT' and str(b) != 'NaT':
        numbusdays.append(np.busday_count(a,b))
    else:
        numbusdays.append(np.nan)

df['numbusdays'] = numbusdays
print(df)
```

```
           ID  Pickup Date Delivery Date  numbusdays
0  1004817295  2019-08-30   2019-09-02         1.0
1  1004833653  2019-08-30          NaT         NaN
2  1004852236  2019-08-30   2019-09-02         1.0
3  1012884202  2019-10-21   2019-10-22         1.0
4  1037931016  2019-08-19   2019-08-22         3.0
```

Comment: I had to add ```.values.astype('datetime64[D]')``` to the df['Pickup Date'] and df['Delivery Date'] and then this worked. Thanks!